# How do I get my Access Token from the New Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Instagram has discontinued their old API and I'm trying to show another feed on a website. I was not able to create a new access token through a tester account on facebook for developers, but this access token comes in a different format and doesn't work on my old feed.

My old feed was using https://api.instagram.com/v1

and I was calling it like this:

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                userId: '123123123',
                limit: 12,
                resolution: 'standard_resolution',
                accessToken: '123123123.testtest.d9128u12u312oijd0',
                sortBy: 'most-recent',
                template: '<div class="gallery instaimg"><a href="{{image}}" title="{{caption}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}" class="img-fluid"/></a></div>',
            });
```

The new access token is much longer, no dots. It's a completely different format. The old one looked something like this
123123123.testtest.d9128u12u312oijd0

Comment: What are you using to display your feed?

Answer (score 1):

```
  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={instagram-app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope={scope}
  &response_type=code
```

you need to use like this after set your program at https://developers.facebook.com/

and it will you give you a code like

```
RSATsRW.c3rwde...
```

after  that you post that

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
  -F client_id=990602627938098 \
  -F client_secret=eb8c7... \
  -F grant_type=authorization_code \
  -F redirect_uri=https://socialsizzle.herokuapp.com/auth/ \
  -F code=RSATsRW.c3rwde...
```

and it will you your token,username,and id

I took that from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions